# Why Xamarin renders nothing when I try to access a property of the binded object?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, binding

One of my Xamarin MVVM application’s pages is here presented. Its XAML code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ...>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView Command="{Binding Load}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
           <ScrollView>
              <Label Text="{Binding MyClass.MyProperty}"/>    
           </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
   public partial class MyPage {
      private readonly MyModel _viewModel;
      
      public NewsDetailPage() {
         InitializeComponent();
         BindingContext = _viewModel = new MyModel();
      }

      protected override void OnAppearing() {
         base.OnAppearing();
         _viewModel.OnAppearing();
      }
   }
}
```

This is the view model:

```
namespace MyOtherNamespace {
   public class MyModel {
      private string _myProperty;

      public MyModel() {
         MyClass = new MyClass ();
         Load= new Command(async () => await GetFromAPI("one"));
      }

      public Command Load { get; set; }
      public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
      
      public string MyProperty{
         get => _myProperty;
         set {
            _date= _myProperty;
            SetProperty(ref _myProperty, value);
         }
      }

      public void OnAppearing() {
         IsBusy = true;
      }


      public async Task GetFromAPI(string x) {
         // News = load from a Web API and populates the MyProperty property
      }
}
```

Finally, the MyType class is defined as:

```
public class MyClass {
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can’t figure out why `<Label Text="{Binding MyClass.MyProperty}"/>` shows nothing, even if I checked that, durig debugging, the property gest populated correctly from inside the `GetFromAPI()` method of the view model.

Comment: your `MyClass` property is of type `News`, not type `MyClass`.  Does `News` have a property named `MyProperty`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed.

Comment: Please take the time to **accurately** post your code.  Its very frustrating to spend time trying to help when every issue I find it just a "typo" you made when posting your code.  As currently posted, your property `MyString` does not contain any value so of course it will not display anything in your UI.

Comment: you can easily test this by setting a default value `public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "test";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the `MyClass` and it works on my side:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        MyClass = new MyClass();
        MyClass.MyProperty = "abc";

        Load = new Command(async () => await GetFromAPI("one"));            
    }

    public Command Load { get; set; }
    public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }

    public bool IsBusy { get; private set; }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    }

    public async Task GetFromAPI(string x)
    {
        // News = load from a Web API and populates the MyProperty property

        MyClass.MyProperty = "efg";
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string myProperty { get; set; }

    public string MyProperty
    {
        set
        {
            if (myProperty != value)
            {
                myProperty = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
    }
}
```